# untar OpenFoam v2012 on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS under WSL2

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, symbolic-link, tar, chown, 7zip

I try to follow the OpenFOAM installation guide on Windows 10.

However I can't get to the final files as I get trouble with the following command:

'''sudo tar -xvzf  OpenFOAM-v2012-windows10.tgz -C /opt/''' gives a numerous of lines and then a tar.file

but the command '''sudo chown -R $USER /opt/OpenFOAM''' doesn't give anything and I am stuck there.

Morevover when I try to use 7-Zip (as administrator) I then get a huge amount of the following error " cannot create symbolic link :.."

Would anyone advice me on how to sort this ?

Many thanks

Comment: *"doesn't give anything"* is normal in *nix when a command succeeds

Comment: thank you. then I carried on the installation but at the final stage it failed: '''Could not find mandatory etc entry (mode=ugo) 'ControlDict' ''' Any suggestion why that happens ?